# Do hospitals have to provide wheelchairs at the entrance to patients and visitors?

Tags: united-states, health, disabilities, wisconsin

I was performing a project at the hospitals and the number of missing wheelchairs, I was just wondering if hospitals must provide wheelchairs at the entrance per [ADA regulation](https://www.ada.gov/) or some other regulation?

The hospitals in particular that I am interested in are in Wisconsin in the US, specifically Mayo Hospitals.

Comment: Which country? What type of hospitals?  Please provide a link to whatever regulation you are referring to, and the relevant passage.

Comment: I have helped with a link to the ADA regulations, however, more needs to be added by you as per @GrahamChiu's comment as the way things are, the question is a little vague.  What state?  What hospitals?  What departments?

Comment: Well I do not have a link to regulation as I cannot find any regulation on the wheelchairs. I am interested in finding such a regulation. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "missing wheelchairs?" Do you mean entrances that didn't have wheelchairs waiting there? Or something else?

Comment: Looks like the person who asked this question in Law.SE sought follow up information in health.SE which kicked it back here.